# Can I delete a JAR after I accesed its internal file through URL?

Tags: java, url, groovy

In Groovy, I am reading a file from inside a JAR, and after some processing, I wish to delete this JAR, but once accessed through the URL, it doesn't seem to let me.

Example:

```
File jarFile = new File('jarFile.jar')
URL url = jarFile.toURI().toURL()

URL intUrl = new URL("jar:$url!/internalFile.json")
println intUrl.text // reads text correctly

jarFile.delete() // returns false, cannot delete
```

The Javadoc of the **getText()** command says the connection is closed at the end of the call, and this JAR normally isn't on classpath. Is there any way to make this code work?

Comment: Gradle 1.0 with Groovy 1.8.6. But I tried this with straight Java 7 code too, using input streams. Same problem.

Comment: Hmmm...  Might be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997902/can-a-loaded-jar-be-deleted-by-the-java-process Are you on Windows?

Comment: It's Windows, and the problem does look similar. Only I don't need any actual class loading, I just read some config data. Maybe in the background, the same thing happens?

Comment: That's what I was wondering... Problem is, I'm on OS X so it's hard to test :-(

Comment: Thanks anyway :) For now I will extract only the files I need into some temp dir.

Comment: Added a new answer that uses `ZipFile` instead of going through the Jar file reader (which might be causing the locking issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `sun.zip.disableMemoryMapping` system property:

```
java -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true ....
```

(or however you set system properties when invoking Gradle).  `ZipFile` (which backs `jar:` URLs) uses memory mapping by default, and this may be causing Windows to think that the file in question is still open.  If this is not an option then you could try using the `commons-compress` ZipFile implementation instead of the `java.util.zip` one:

```
@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-compress', version='1.4.1')
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.*

File jarFile = new File('jarFile.jar')
ZipFile f = new ZipFile(jarFile)
ZipArchiveEntry json = f.getEntry('internalFile.json')
if(json) {
  f.getInputStream(json)?.withStream {
    println it.getText('UTF-8')
  }
}
f.close()
jarFile.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import java.util.zip.ZipFile

File jarFile = new File( 'jarFile.jar' )

String text = new ZipFile( jarFile ).with { zf ->
  String result = zf.entries().findResult { ze ->
    if( ze.name == 'internalFile.json' ) {
      zf.getInputStream( ze ).withReader {
        it.text
      }
    }
  }
  zf.close()
  result
}

println text

jarFile.delete()
```

To avoid (what I suspect is) the classloader locking the jar file