# Java keeping jar in use by jarclassloader/urlclassloader

Tags: java, file, urlclassloader

I am loading a jar file with a `JarClassLoader`. After the jar file is loaded, I want to delete the file. Everything works fine except for deleting the file because the file is kept in use by the Java jvm. How do I unlock the jar? I am already closing all my `inputstreams` and closing the `urlclassloader`.

Thank you,
Ridz

Comment: have you checked this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997902/can-a-loaded-jar-be-deleted-by-the-java-process

Comment: Thanks, I have now. However, I am not trying to uninstall something and the process with remain alive until forever. I can't wait until the process dies out, unfortunately. I am, like the second answer suggests, closing the urlclassloader.

Comment: I followed the URL posted in second answer and it seems promising

Comment: As I said, I am already closing the urlclassloader.